# Add image as header for when using window.print()

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, media

Good day,

I am using `window.print()` to print a page.
Now I wish to add an image as a header when I click the print button.

I know that we can use `@media print{ div.header{ display: none; }}`.

But what I one is, write a common code so that it can apply to each page for the print button. As I have thousand of page contain this print button. If I using the method I mention just now, I need to go every jsp page to add in the header, which is very time consuming and not good for future maintenance.

I tried something as follow but its failed:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @media print{
        #header {
          display: table-header-group;
          background-image: url('../images/red_icon.png');
        }
    }
</style>
```

Anyone have any good solution?

Or Maybe I can change my question, which is can I import a jsp into css file?
For example, I have `@media print` in a css file, and then I will do something like:

```
@media print {
    header {
         background-image: url('../images/red_icon.png');
      // or 
         source : ../myHeader.jsp;
         height: 12px;
         width: 12px;
    }
}
```

So that everytime I click on the window.print() button, it will auto put this `red_icon.png`